# Launchpad logins broken on linux browsers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, launchpad

One of my coworkers noticed that Launchpad logins are broken. If you log out, then go to login, click the launchpad button, and nothing happens.

Normally a text widget shows up so you can type in your username and then login.

Works on Chrome for Windows but neither Chrome or Firefox in Linux. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: Probably better tested in a new private browsing session (control+shift+p in Firefox, control+shift+n in Chrome) to clear any trace of a session.

Answer (score 8):

This is fixed now.

When selecting the Launchpad option, a username field will come up:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Apologies for breaking it in the first place...

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm the behaviour but it isn't terminal.

If you click the "More sign up options" link and then click the "Sign up using Launchpad" link, you'll get a textbox that will pre-populate the OpenID box for you and will forward you onto Launchpad.

[image]

It's definitely a problem though. I'll punt this off to SE directly.

Update: It's been handed from SE mods to developers. I or they will let you know when this is fixed.